# Canvas image generation by Div id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have planned to generate image as canvas if we applied styles to div tag means how should we export that?

```
var Pic = document.getElementById("shirtDiv").toDataURL("image/png");
```

I have used above line for export image by div id. My div id is `shirtDiv`.

```
var Pic = document.getElementById("shirtDiv").toDataURL("image/png");
```

I need to download image in `1:1` ratio.

Comment: `toDataURL()` is specific to `<canvas>` elements, so you can not call that on a `<div>`. If you want to render HTML and exports it via a canvas, I think you have to create an SVG image, insert the HTML as `<foreignObject>`, and then draw it using `.drawImage()`. Afterwards, you can export that via `toDataURL()` from the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is when you change width and height properties. What i suggest you is to never modified those one. If you need to adjust canvas size to your view, use scale instead. This will make you able to always get the same image dimensions when exporting !

Comment: is there any possible to convert div as canvas image using id?

Comment: No you can't "draw" html into canvas. But you can do some hack to render an equivalent svg image and then draw it : https://reference.codeproject.com/book/dom/canvas_api/drawing_dom_objects_into_a_canvas